# rebinding jquery after angular js ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm filling in an array in angularJS using `$http.get()` service, by calling a rest api. This array is displayed using `ng-repeat`. There is Jquery code to display a button on hovering over each of the `<li>` tags. `$http` causes a delay in fetching the data, by which time Jquery would have finished binding. So the hover function doesn't work. Any work arounds for this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
});
var myFunction= function(){
$("#orders ul li").hover(
        function() {
            $(this ).find(".butt-view").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this ).find(".butt-view").hide();
        });
}
</script>
<script>
function PhoneListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.phones = $http.get(url);
}
</script>
<style>
ul{list-style-type:none;}
ul li{background-color:#e1eff2; padding:5px 6px;}
ul li:hover{background-color:#fff;}
.butt-view{background-color:#feb801; border-radius:4px; color:#fff; font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; padding:5px 7px; margin-top:3px; width:40px }
</style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
<div id="orders">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones" >
  {{phone.name}}
  <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
  <p class="butt-view">View</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), which is better approach introduced by the new `.on()` jQuery method, to do it just replace your following code:

```
$("#orders ul li").hover(
        function() {
            $(this ).find(".butt-view").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this ).find(".butt-view").hide();
        });
```

for this one:

```
$("#orders").on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'li', function(event) {
     if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
         $(this ).find(".butt-view").show();
     } else  {
         $(this ).find(".butt-view").hide();
     }
});
```

This way you will attach your event handler to your `#orders` div, instead of the individual `li` elements, when a `li` element is hovered the event will bubble up till gets to your handler on `#orders`. This approach is more eficient and will work for dinamycally added new li's.

By the way I'm using  `mouseenter mouseleave` events which are equivalent to `hover` and are more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much! It worked. You have no idea how much time I've spent trying to solve this.

Answer (score 17):

While the jQuery approach might work OK this is not really an AngularJS-way of solving the problem.

AngularJS promotes UI expressed in declarative way (in other words we do describe a desired effect instead of indicating each and every little step to take in order to achieve the effect). **Using directives we can tell AngularJS how we want our UI to look like in response to model mutations. So, with AngularJS we more focus on declaratively describing UI in a template and then driving this UI by model mutations**. AngularJS will do the rest of heavy -lifting.

This all might sound a bit cryptic so here is the problem solved the AngularJS way (the model doesn't change, only template does):

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones" ng-mouseenter="showView=true" ng-mouseleave="showView=false">
  {{phone.name}}
  <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
  <p class="butt-view" ng-show="showView">View</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Please note that this is *all* what is needed to make it work: no need to ad ids to the DOM elements and no need to write *any* JavaScript code. **It allows us to remove 14 lines of JavaScript code and remove dependency on jQuery altogether**. Sweet, isn't it?

Finally here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GBwLN/4/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! But it so happens that in my scenario, the HTML & UI was done by someone else. My task was to blend the logic which retrieved the data and displayed in the UI. Thanks again.

Comment: Although this answer wasn't exactly what chai.nadig was looking for, it should be noted to future users finding this question via Google, etc. that this is the correct way of going about something like this in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

You should use event delegation, however you could also achieve this using a directive:

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones" awesome-item>
  {{phone.name}}
  <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
  <p class="butt-view">View</p>
</li>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('darthvader', [])
  .directive('awesomeItem', function() {
    return function($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.hover(function() {
            $(this).find(".butt-view").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find(".butt-view").hide();
        });
    };
  });
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after!